# How to disable JavaScript in IE9 beta?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Is it possible to disable JavaScript in Internet Explorer 9 beta? How?

Comment: If you can't find the `Tools` menu (little cog at top right of IE's window), then try typing Alt-T.

Answer (score 2):

To enable or disable JavaScript:

1. From the Tools menu, or the Tools drop-down in the upper right, choose Internet Options... .
2. Click the Security tab.
3. Click Custom Level... .
4. Scroll to the "Scripting" section of the list. Click Disable or Enable.
5. Close and restart your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following after choosing the appropriate zone (Internet, Local intranet, etc.) for which you want to change the settings.

Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level -> Scripting - Active scripting : Disable